# Moving average calculation for empty points in excel

Tags: excel, msdn, excel-charts, trendline

I am generating trendline for the given data points using excel trendline formula. In normal case (without empty points) moving average is working fine. But i not able to proceed with empty points for moving average trendline. I couldn't find out the moving average formula for empty points. Please refer the below excel moving average chart with period 2

[image]

If i changed period value to 3, this empty point value changed

[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, moving average is like this:

```
     A     B     C     D
----+-----------------------
1   |x     y     MA(2) MA(3)
2   |1     1 
3   |2     5     3  
4   |3     17    11    7.67
5   |4           17    11
6   |5     4     4     10.5
```

It has nothing to do with an empty point (more precisely, missing data). MA with interval 2 is calculated based on (ie, taking average of) current and a previous value. So `C3` is `=AVERAGE(B2:B3)`, `C4` is `=AVERAGE(B3:B4)`, and so on.

Likewise MA with interval 3 is calculated based on current and previous two values. `D4` is `=AVERAGE(B2:B4)`, `D5` is `=AVERAGE(B3:B5)`, and `D6` is `=AVERAGE(B4:B6)`. You can see that those MA values are exact the same in the plot.

This is called simple moving average. You'd better read [this article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/09/25/moving-average-excel/) for more gentle explanation.